# Cannot find syntax error in bib-file

Tags: biblatex, biber

I somehow messed up my bib-file. I have several entries that worked just fine until a few hours ago.

Now I have added a couple more entries, and I always get `line 54, syntax error: found "and", expected "="` trying to compile with Biber.

Line 54 points to the author-line of the first **new** entry in the bib. When I delete ALL entries I made during the last few hours and only keep those I had before it stopped working, I can compile just fine again. As soon as I add just one of the new entries (regardless which one it is), I get the syntax error on its author line. Switching around the entries still makes the error appear on the first new author line it hits during compilation. This is true even if I try to "hide" a new entry between the old ones.

One of the "offending" entries (can serve as an example, as adding this to my bib file from earlier today causes the error, reverting to the old bib-file compiles fine):

```
@article{phillips2020,
author = “Phillips, B. and Allder, J. and Bolan, G. and Nagle, R. and Redington, A. and Hellebrekers, T. and Borden, J. and Pawlenko, N. and Licht, S.”,
title = “Additive manufacturing aboard a moving vessel at sea using passively stabilized stereolithography (SLA) 3D printing”,
journaltitle = “Additive Manufacturing”,
year = “2020”,
issue = “31”,
doi = “10.1016/j.addma.2019.100969”,
url = “https://repository.library.noaa.gov/view/noaa/49292/noaa{\_}49292{\_}DS1.pdf”,
urldate = “2024-03-23”,
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Solved it by posting here:
I somehow switched TeXworks to unicode quotation marks `“”`, while of course Biber needs `""`. In TeXworks, both variants look exactly alike for me, so I didn't notice until posting here.

Comment: A reason to use the IMHO the clearer syntax of `field = {content },` Moreover some tools as JabRef will change to this syntax automatically if you edit the field, losing the syntax uniformity  (a bit annoying if you later edit the file as plain text).

Comment: Good point, though I find it difficult to keep track of all the curly brackets inside curly brackets. Using quotation marks where possible helps me tracking down syntax errors later.